# Nicescroll, проблема в стилизации

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, прокрутка

Загрузил к документу скрипт плагина `nicescroll.js`, всё работает в целом, но вот есть беда.

При такой структуре `html`,  горизонтальный и вертикальный скрол найс скролла, находится выше на `100px`, чем  ожидаемое его местопоявление и левее тоже примерно на `100px`.

```css
*{
margin-top: 5px;
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
}

li{
background: whitesmoke;
}

.target{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
} 


.target:hover div{
display: inline-block;
}
.target div{
display: none;
background: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a></a>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="target">Нужный элемент
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $(".target").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor:"#6dc0c8", 
        background:"#ecedee", 
        autohidemode:"false", 
        cursorborder:"none", 
        cursorborderradius:"none"
      });
  });
</script>
```

Вопрос знатокам. В данном примере все работает, но может быть у вас случалось похожие ситуации как у меня, или вы можете подсказать в чем может быть проблема и я сочту это за ответ.